# Media Queries in Email Signatures?

Tags: css, email, html-email

I'm aware you can send out HTML emails with media queries - although some clients will strip these, so should have a decent fallback.

But what about email signatures. Do clients support  tags for email signatures?

Comment: Depends on what you are sending it thru. If you want to paste it into Outlook to send then it wouldnt work. Not sure about Gmail as it's just an editor

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the email client and if an email is replied to or forwarded. In my experience, email signatures with media queries fare well in clients that... of course, support media queries. Conversely, they shouldn't work in Win Outlook.

If an email is forwarded or replied to, and email's media queries fare only as good as the worst email client in the mix.

Eg:

- ✅ If the original email is replied to from iOS Mail, media queries should be in tact.
- ✅ If this email is replied to from someone else's iOS Mail, media queries should *still* be in tact.
- ❌ If this email is replied to from Outlook, Outlook removes or otherwise screws up the media query for *everyone* going forward.

This is all based on my experience designing emails that render properly when forwarded. Worth testing!

---

To @Syfer's comment, it also depends on where the email is being sent from. Eg. An email with media queries being sent from Win Outlook won't render the media queries.